# Issue with "git pull"

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Yesterday I encountered the following behaviour using the GIT command line (and Eclipse). 
Via command line I did

```
git pull origin master
```

Afterwards Eclipse showed me that my branch is 14 commits ahead of the remote branch

I resetted the branch to the remote branch via

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

I pulled again, same result.

Then I used

```
git fetch origin master
git pull origin master
```

I could see some files are updated and in Eclipse develop wasn't ahead of master anymore.

From my understanding git pull should be like a fetch + a merge, meaning that the encountered behaviour is either a bug or a misconfiguration.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem I encountered could be? Or do I get something wrong?

Many Thanks
Paul

Comment: Please insure that: 1) master branch connected to the origin/master 2) you do auto-refresh in eclipse or refresh manually after each operation from command line. You could also inspect situation with `gitk --all`.

Comment: Hi Boris, thanks for reply. 1) could you please advise how I can ensure this? 2) I have auto refresh, but I also refreshed it manually to be sure.

Comment: Issue `git config --list`. You should see something like `branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master`.

Comment: Hi Boris, thanks. Yes I can see exactly this.

Comment: Can you confirm the same behavior with Eclipse closed? (use gitk --all to examine the situation) Are those 14 commits from you?

Comment: Hi Boris, unfortunately I cannot reproduce the situation anymore, because sine I mafe this manual fetch everything works as expected. I was just very confused that after a "pull" it was possible that I was ahead of orign/master.  I don't think my problem was limited to Eclipse, because when I did the manual fetch and the next pull did the trick. However just to double-check. In theory pull should defintily "include" a fetch, correct?

Comment: Yes, `git pull` includes `git fetch`

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on the version of EGit (and of your Eclipse), but one way to ensure a full synchronisation of a local branch after a git pull is to do (or even redo in your case) the `git pull` from Eclipse itself.

See "[Pulling New Changes from Upstream Branch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pulling_New_Changes_from_Upstream_Branch) ":

> Right-click on a project in the Package Explorer and select **`Team > Pull`** or right-click on a repository in the Git Repositories view and select **`Pull`** to pull new changes from the upstream branch your local branch is tracking.
>   This also works if resources are selected from more than one repository.